# Wordpress - How to display 10 users only?

Tags: php, wordpress, author

Sorry I'm newbie with Wordpress, How to display 10 users only and the others inside "see more".

I searched more times before asking but with nothing!

Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
$post_id = get_the_ID();
$users_liked = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_user_liked', true );

if ( '' !== $users_liked && ! empty( $users_liked ) ) {
?>

<span>Liked:</span></br>
<?php foreach ( array_values( $users_liked ) as $user_id ) : 

$user = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id );

if ( false === $user ) {
  continue;
}
?>

<div class="sort-list-name">

    <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url($user->ID);?>">
        <?php echo get_avatar( $user->ID, 35 ); ?>  
    </a>

</div>

<?php

 endforeach; ?>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first off all try to add  an index in your loop

```
<?php
$post_id = get_the_ID();
$i = 0;
$users_liked = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_user_liked', true );

if ( '' !== $users_liked && ! empty( $users_liked ) ) {
?>

<span>Liked:</span></br>
<?php foreach ( array_values( $users_liked ) as $user_id ) : 

$user = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id );

if ( false === $user ) {
  continue;
}
?>

<div class="sort-list-name">

    <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url($user->ID);?>">
        <?php echo get_avatar( $user->ID, 35 ); ?>  
    </a>

</div>

<?php

 if ($i++ == 9){
  echo "<a href='#'>see more</a>";
  break;
  } 

 endforeach; ?>

<?php } ?>
```

and then if $i get 9 the loop will be break

Comment: Thanks @SamirGuiderk, it working :), but what about the others? is there anyway to display them?

Comment: No, because you want just to display 10 items, for the others, I'm not sure

Comment: I suggeste to using the pagination system ?

Comment: yes sure check out this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15940681/pagination-of-users-in-the-custom-page

Comment: Thanks for your help bro, Last question please..How can I make it " if count 10 show only the first 10 users! and if count++ more than 10 show `<a href="#">see more</a>` to external link.

Comment: there you are, I edited my answer  please do not forget to accept my answer.